# python code for print data in csv

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping

import csv

reader = csv.reader(post.text, quotechar="'")

with open('source91.csv', 'wb') as f:

```
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerows(list(reader))
```

output is showing vertically i need to print the data horizantally in CSV

Comment: getiing output in csv but printing vertically....

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Answer : if you have only one array**

```
with open('source91.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\n')
    writer.writerows(list(reader))
```

**Complicated answer:**

you may need `numpy` to make is happen. 
`transpose` will simply converts row to column

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(list(reader))
a = np.append(a, list(reader)) # if you have multiple lines 
a = np.transpose(a)
np.savetxt('source91.csv', a)
```

Comment: after executing above code the file is saved in NPY file...but i want to save  it as CSV

Comment: i am having lots of data in post.text variable

Comment: savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments)  savetxt support only these getting error             TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')